# Blogger template post thumbnails sometimes overlap each other if they did not load fast enough

Tags: css, web, responsive-design, blogger

If my post thumbnails do not load quick enough the whole responsive layout of my post-thumbnails gets messed up requiring a refresh. Is it possible to add a code that tells it to still load the proper space even if the image has not finished loading or perhaps a code to have it load a placeholder image until the real one loads? Below is some code and a screenshot of the glitch. Site can be found at http://centerice.frozenfaceoff.net/

```
/* CSS Post Thumbnail */
.post img{display:block;width:100%;height:100%;cursor:default;}
.img-thumbnail {background:#f9f9f9;position:relative;float:left;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:0;}
.img-thumbnail img {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0 auto;}
span.overlay {background:rgba(0,0,0,0);cursor:pointer;position:absolute;right:0;left:0;
bottom:0;top:0;z-index:1;opacity:1;width:100%;height:100%;transition:all .3s linear;}
span.overlay:hover {background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);opacity:1;transition:all .3s linear;}
span.overlay:before {content:&quot;\f002&quot;;font-family:FontAwesome;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size: 24px;width:24px;height:24px;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-20px;padding:10px;position:absolute;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);-ms-transform: scale(1.6);-webkit-transform: scale(1.6);-moz-transform: scale(1.6);transform: scale(1.6);transition:all .3s linear;-moz-transition:all .3s linear;-webkit-transition:all .3s linear;}
span.overlay:hover:before {color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);text-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);-ms-transform: scale(1.0);-webkit-transform: scale(1.0);-moz-transform: scale(1.0);transform: scale(1.0);transition:all .3s linear;-moz-transition:all .3s linear;-webkit-transition:all .3s linear;}
```

[image]

Here is the code for .post-outer. I attempted to change this to float:none as well but that did not solve the issue.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<style type='text/css'>
#wrapper{overflow:hidden;width:1100px;max-width:100%;margin:0 auto;margin-top:0;}
#post-wrap{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.blog-posts{margin-bottom:20px;}
#part-aside{width:1100px;max-width:100%;margin:0 auto;}
.post{background:#fff;position:relative;padding:10px;margin:10px;border-bottom:2px solid #dcdcdc;}
.post-outer{width:25%;float:left;position:relative;overflow:hidden;display:block;margin:0 auto;}
.post-body {display:none;max-width:100%;line-height:1.6em;color:#999;margin:15px auto;font-size:11px;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-align:center;}
.post h2.post-title {white-space:nowrap;min-height:100%;bottom:0;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0 auto;background:transparent;position:relative;text-decoration:none;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;}
h2.post-title span a{color:#D24647;}
.post:hover h2.post-title {z-index:2;color:#d76c58;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;}
h2.post-title a {overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-align:center;font-size:13px;display:block;line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:0.5px;background:#fff;color:#999;padding:0px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #f5f5f5;transition:all .3s ease-in-out;}
h2.post-title a:hover{color:#D24647;}
.post:hover h2.post-title a{color:#D24647;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `float` and property on the `post-outer` selector. Change the `float` property as follows -

```
.post-outer {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: I think it is more of a vertical issue, where if the images have not loaded fast enough, it does not allow enough vertical space for the thumbnails once it does load. 

I tried to change this float but the problem persists.